# Autofill Django signup page with automatically generated password

Tags: python, django

I created a simple page for staff members that adds users by entering a username and password, very similar to the way users are added in the admin page. How can the password field be automatically filled with a random password instead of staff members having to manually enter one in?

I have seen a method that sends the user a password-reset email, allowing them to enter their own password. This method however doesn't suit our needs.

Please take it step by step as I am still new to this language.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the SO! See, when asking questions, always try to include the code you've been working on. This helps us understand what you’re doing, so we can give you more specific answers to your problem.

Comment: I definitely will next time. Thanks for the advice Ralubrusto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is generate a random string and pass it to the password input in your form like this:

**views.py**

```
import random
import string

def register_new_user(request):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    password = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST) # your signup form class
        if form.is_valid():
            user.save()
            return redirect('home') # redirect to a valid page
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'register_new_user.html' {'form': form, 
                                                     'password': password})
```

Then in your template pass the password inside your password input field **value** attribute:

**register_new_user.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password }}">
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password }}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This way each time a user accesses your `register_new_user` view the password fields will be prepopulated with random string.

Comment: Had to change the placeholder attribute to a value attribute in order for it to work, but other than that, it worked perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah yes, excuse me, got that one wrong :) Feel free to accept the answer if its not hard, I appreciate it :)